# find all pdf files in a directory at one level

Tags: bash, find, cp

I would like to copy all pdf files from a directory to an other, but not pdf files at the next level ...

exemple Source :

```
>tree
.
├── bestiole
│   ├── Bestiole_fiche.pdf
│   ├── bestiole_modele.nlogo
│   └── README.txt
├── Bestiole_fiche.pdf
├── bestiole_modele.nlogo
├── christaller
│   ├── Christaller_Fiche.pdf
│   ├── Christaller_Modele.nlogo
│   └── README.txt
├── Christaller_Fiche.pdf
├── Christaller_Modele.nlogo
├── compress_zip.sh
├── epiSim
│   ├── EpiSim_Fiche.pdf
│   ├── EpiSim_Math_Modele.nlogo
│   ├── EpiSim_Modele.nlogo
│   └── README.txt
```

move only Bestiole_fiche.pdf , Christaller_Fiche.pdf ... from the 1st level to an other directory ... I have tried :

```
find -name "*.pdf" -exec cp -f {} ~/github/maps/fichesPedago/{} \;
```

It work but with some errors ... there is something more elegante?

thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have control over the levels of directory you want to traverse, use `maxdepth` option provided in `find` command. For details, you can refer the man page: `man find`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec cp -f {} ~/github/maps/fichesPedago/ \;
```

You should also check the `mindepth` option of `find` command. Using both `maxdepth` and `mindepth` comes quite handy at times.

Answer (score 2):

If you want files from the current directory only, you can do this very simply without using `find`:

```
cp *.pdf ~/github/maps/fichesPedago/
```

Or is there something more complicated I did not see?

Comment: @delaye: add a `-v` after `cp` to see what happens.